# CIIImage leaks when I try to perform a rotation off-screen on up to 100 images

Tags: ios, rotation, cgaffinetransform

When I use the following method (under ARC) the memory allocation grows rapidly up to more than 125 Mo.

I have implemented it using CGImage but it's rather slow.

imageArray contains 125 UIImage of size 640x80.

```
-(void)rotateAndTransform{
int j=0; 
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
for(UIImage* item in imageArray) 
{
CGImageRef intermed =[item CGImage];
CIImage *begin = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:intermed];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
CIImage *outputImage = [ begin imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
[self.imagesFromExtract addObject:newImg]; 
j++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that this like

```
CIImage *outputImage = [ begin imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
```

allocates an image which will not be released until the autorelease pool is drained, which happens when your program reaches the idle loop. Without having tried your code, may I suggest you wrap the inner loop in a

```
@autoreleasepool {
    ...
}
```

block?

Comment: It did not solve the issue when I used the @autoreleasepool for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
```

Is not a problem, you're adding newImg to array, so it should not be destroyed after exit from  method.
Problem is

```
CIImage *outputImage = [ begin imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
```

, but anyway, suggestion to use

```
@autoreleasepool {
...
}
```

is good.

Also, if you don't need input images anymore, you can try to remove them from array after creating newImg.

Comment: You are right. I was too quick in copy/pasting there. I edited my answer.